# Using the 'locate' command on hidden folders

Tags: osx-lion

I recently tried to `locate` a file called `id_rsa` to figure out whether a user had already generated public key. I ran `locate id_rsa`, but nothing showed up. I even searched for `.ssh` but couldn't find it. The folder exists and so does the file, but the folder is hidden.

So, how do I get `locate` to actually look through *every* ***single*** file and folder on the system?

Comment: Did you do `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` first?

Comment: What is that supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to regenerate the database that `locate` uses for locating files. If the file is recent, it is possible that it hasn't made it into the database yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is an approach using find:

```
find /path/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname ".*"
```

You can use " * " instead of "/path/folder" to search every place. Also you can modify -maxdepth for the amount of subfolders you want to go search into and -type d if you want to search for a folder instead of a file.

Comment: This is an alternative but does not answer the question on how to make the locate(1) utility to index dot files.